# Multiple NetSuite Script Event Types

Tags: events, scripting, netsuite

I'm new to NetSuite and have been tasked with integrating another system with NetSuite.  I've created a User Event script that needs to run against multiple NetSuite events.  The deployment interface seems to only let me assign the script to Create OR Edit, but not both.  Is this not possible or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read through [this page and links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and edit. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the events on which the UE script runs within the script, and leave the event type assignment in the deployment record blank.

Firstly, if you leave the event type blank in the UI and don't include logic withing the script to limit when it runs, it will be triggered on *all* event types (create, edit etc) whenever the triggering event occurs (beforeLoad, beforeSubmit, afterSubmit).

Selecting the event type in the UI is an easy shortcut to limiting when a script runs without having to worry about additional script logic; however, for maximum flexibility you can use script logic as follows or modify to suit your needs (in SS2.0):

```
function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
    log.debug('type', scriptContext.type);
    if (scriptContext.type !== scriptContext.UserEventType.CREATE) {
        log.error('Exiting script', 'Context type is ' + scriptContext.type);
        return;
    }
    //Do your work here
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It's useful to know that not declaring conditional logic within the script nor setting it in the deployment form causes the script to run on all events.  If I pass the type back to my integration script I can then handle how the other system should deal with the NS record change.  Thanks!